# sql server 2014 - Count(*) and multiplication

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling with a simple task:
I have a table as follows:

```
ID  UserID  OrderID     Quantity        Price   ItemID  Status
1   John        25          2           3.50    ...     Open
2   Jack        26          1           2.00    ...     Open
3   John        27          2           1.25    ...     Open
4   John        28          3           1.50    ...     Closed
```

And needed to know how many orders were open for John

I built the simple query as follows:

```
select count(ID) cnt from Orders where UserID='John' and Status='Open'
```

now I need to check also the total amount of the open orders 
but changing the query in the following way

```
select count(ID) as cnt, Quantiy*Price as Amount from Orders where UserID='John'...
```

does not work

Perhaps I can get the number of Orders from @@RowCount, but I was wondering if there is a better solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use non aggregate column along with `Count(*)` in `Select` unless they are in `Group By`

Use `SUM` aggregate to get the total sum of open orders for `John`

```
select count(ID) as cnt, 
       sum(Quantiy*Price) as Amount 
from Orders 
where UserID='John' and Status='Open'
```

Comment: yes, right, but I could'nt group.... did not thought that sum is an aggregate function..
thanks a lot!